# store 2 values in an array from event handler

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator in c# I want to store the operand and operator in an 2d array and then when the equals button is pressed the code can go through to collect the values and then apply the operand. Im having problems getting the values into the array. here is what i have

```
operandAndOperator[i] = { Convert.ToInt32(outputBox.Text), 4 };
```

On the MS website it says to use { and put what you want in the array in, seperated by a comma. Any help would be appreicated

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the array object too.

```
operandAndOperator[i] = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(outputBox.Text), 4 };
```

You can be more or less explicit about the array in this case, so these two options would be valid as well:

```
operandAndOperator[i] = new [] { Convert.ToInt32(outputBox.Text), 4 };
operandAndOperator[i] = new int[2] { Convert.ToInt32(outputBox.Text), 4 };
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I have created the array at the start of the program, When the event handler is called for the button pressed is when operandAndOperator[i] = { Convert.ToInt32(outputBox.Text), 4 }; is used

Comment: You said this was a 2d array, so I'm assuming operandAndOperator is of type int[][]. Even if you've created that object, that only covers the first dimension. Each element of the second dimension must be created separately.